# MySQL/PHP: Los datos han sido introducidos en el POST pero el codigo siempre termina en el statement ELSE

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy creando un programa que recoge los datos de un formulario anterior y mediante POST los insertara en la base de datos, en estos momentos esta insertando los datos en la tabla pero por alguna razon la cual no acabo de encontrar la falla es que el programa siempre termina ejecutando el ELSE donde este le indica al usuario mediante un script de alerta un mensaje. Pese a cambios en el codigo no he conseguido encontrar el problema.

### HTML/FORM

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<title>TITULO</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Form_files/view.css" media="all">

<script>
function change() {
var oItem = document.getElementById('optionvals');
var value = oItem.options[oItem.selectedIndex].value;
  if(value == "no") {
   alert("Solo los equipos conectado en red se pueden conectar a @remote");
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body id="main_body" class="no_guidelines safari">


    <div id="form_container">

        <img src="./Form_files/logo.jpg" style=" display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;width: 15%;padding-top: 20px">
                <div class="form_description"></div>



        <div id="formulario">

        <form id="form_50503" class="appnitro" method="post" action="./Form_files/addentry.php">

            <ul>
            <li id="li_6">
        <label class="description" for="element_6">Empresa: </label>
        <div>
            <input id="empresa" name="empresa" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="50" style="border-radius:20px;" required> 
        </div> 
        </li>
                    <li id="li_1">
        <label class="description" for="element_1">Persona de contacto: </label>
        <div>
            <input id="per_contacto" name="per_contacto" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="50" style="border-radius:20px;" required> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_2">
        <label class="description" for="element_2">Teléfono de contacto: </label>
        <div>
            <input id="tel_contacto" name="tel_contacto" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="9" style="border-radius:20px;" required> 
        </div> 
        <label class="description" for="element_2">Correo electrónico: </label>
        <div>
            <input id="email" name="email" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="20" style="border-radius:20px;" required> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_3">
        <label class="description" for="element_3">Horario de disponibilidad: </label>
        <div>
        <br>
<select name="hor_disp_inicio" class="element text medium"style="border-radius:20px;width:24%;text-align:center;" required>
    <option  value="" selected disabled hidden>▼</option>   
    <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
    <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
    <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
    <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
    <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
    <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
    <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
    <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
    <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
    <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
</select> 
<strong> - </strong>
<select name="hor_disp_final" class="element text medium"style="border-radius:25px;width:24%;text-align:center;" required>
    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>▼</option>
    <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
    <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
    <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
    <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
    <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
    <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
    <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
    <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
    <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
    <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
  </select>
</div>
<br>
<div>

<div class="weekDays-selector">
  <input type="checkbox" id="weekday-mon" name="lunes" value="Disponible" class="weekday" />
  <label for="weekday-mon">Lunes</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="weekday-tue" name="martes" value="Disponible" class="weekday" />
  <label for="weekday-tue">Martes</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="weekday-wed" name="miercoles" value="Disponible" class="weekday" />
  <label for="weekday-wed">Miercoles</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="weekday-thu" name="jueves" value="Disponible" class="weekday" />
  <label for="weekday-thu">Jueves</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="weekday-fri" name="viernes" value="Disponible" class="weekday" />
  <label for="weekday-fri">Viernes</label>
  </div>
</div>


        </li>       <li id="li_4">
        <label class="description" for="element_4">Número de serie de la máquina: </label>
        <div>
            <input id="numero_serie" name="numero_serie" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="10"  style="border-radius:20px;" placeholder="X178HA04414" required> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_5">
        <label class="description" for="element_5">Modelo de la máquina: </label>
        <div>
            <input id="modelo_maquina" name="modelo_maquina" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="20" style="border-radius:20px;" required> 
        </div> 
        </li>   
        <li id="li_8">
        <label class="description" for="element_6">IP del equipo: </label>
        <div>
            <input id="ip_maquina" name="ip_maquina" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="50" style="border-radius:20px;" placeholder="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" required> 
        </div> 

        </li>

        </li>   
        <li id="li_8">
        <label class="description" for="element_6">Comentarios adicionales: </label>
        <div>
            <textarea placeholder="Persona de contacto de informática, etc. Máximo 500 caracteres." rows="4" cols="50" class="element text medium" name="comentario" id="comentario" maxlength="500" style="width: 50%;border-radius:10px;text-align:left;"></textarea> 
        </div> 

        </li>

        <br>
        <li class="buttons">
                <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="50503">

                <div id="botones"><input id="saveForm" class="miboton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar"><input id="saveForm" class="miboton" type="reset" name="reset" value="Eliminar"></div>
        </li>
            </ul>

        </form>


</div>      


        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

### PHP

```
<?php
require_once('required/bdd.php');


session_start();


$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","cuenta","password","tabla");


if (isset($_POST['empresa']) && isset($_POST['per_contacto']) && isset($_POST['tel_contacto']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['hor_disp_inicio']) && isset($_POST['hor_disp_final']) 
    && isset($_POST['numero_serie']) && isset($_POST['modelo_maquina']) && isset($_POST['ip_maquina']) && isset($_POST['comentario'])){

    $empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
    $per_contacto = $_POST['per_contacto'];
    $tel_contacto = $_POST['tel_contacto'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $hor_disp_inicio = $_POST['hor_disp_inicio'];
    $hor_disp_final = $_POST['hor_disp_final'];
    $lunes = $_POST['lunes'];
    $martes = $_POST['martes'];
    $miercoles = $_POST['miercoles'];
    $jueves = $_POST['jueves'];
    $viernes = $_POST['viernes'];
    $numero_serie = $_POST['numero_serie'];
    $modelo_maquina = $_POST['modelo_maquina'];
    $ip_maquina = $_POST['ip_maquina'];
    $comentario = $_POST['comentario'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tabla(empresa, per_contacto, tel_contacto, email, hor_disp_inicio, hor_disp_final, lunes, martes, miercoles, jueves, viernes,  numero_serie, modelo_maquina, ip_maquina, comentario) values ('$empresa', '$per_contacto', '$tel_contacto', '$email', '$hor_disp_inicio', '$hor_disp_final', '$lunes', '$martes', '$miercoles',  '$jueves', '$viernes', '$numero_serie', '$modelo_maquina', '$ip_maquina', '$comentario')";




    $query = $bdd->prepare( $sql );
    if ($query == false) {
        print_r($bdd->errorInfo());
        die ('Erreur prepare');
    }
    $sth = $query->execute();
    if ($sth == false) {
        print_r($query->errorInfo());
        die ('Erreur execute');

       header("location: exito.php");
       exit;


    } else { 

         $message = "No has introducido todos los datos necesarios";
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
         header('Refresh: 0; URL=../index.html');

     }
}

?>
```

Edit: Se modifica los datos principales incluyendo el formulario HTML.

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta y añadir tu formulario para ver que nombres tienes?

Comment: Cambios realizados.

Comment: Una cosa que veo rara, pero no tiene nada que ver, al menos creo, en tu formulario, en el select `hor_disp_inicio` tus values son todos iguales.

Comment: Cierto, ahora lo corrigo.

Comment: Entonces tu problema es que no entra en el `f (isset($_POST['empresa']) && isset($_POST['per_contacto'])...` y va directamente al else?  Todos los `$_POST['loquesea']` que estas controlando en el php los mandas desde el formulario?

Comment: muestra un `var_export($_POST)` antes del if

Comment: array ( 'empresa' => 'prueba', 'per_contacto' => 'prueba', 'tel_contacto' => '931231241', 'email' => 'prueba@prueba.com', 'hor_disp_inicio' => '09:00', 'hor_disp_final' => '14:00', 'lunes' => 'Disponible', 'miercoles' => 'Disponible', 'jueves' => 'Disponible', 'numero_serie' => '1231312312', 'modelo_maquina' => 'P402322', 'ip_maquina' => '192.168.20.14', 'comentario' => 'Comentario', 'form_id' => '50503', 'submit' => 'Enviar', )

Comment: @MarioGuiber No creo que ese sea el problema, porque por lo demas esta funcioando el stamenent IF ( el insert me lo hace )

Comment: El probrama esta funcionando correctamente. `$sth` vale true y lo comparas con false por lo que siempre va a ir al else

Comment: @JDev si sth se pone como true no se ejecutara.

Comment: Si la query funciona sth valdra siempre true por lo que entrará en el else. Creo que tu problema es que no has programado la logica que deseas o que has puesto mal alguna llave.

Comment: Repasa el código, el `else` (el único que existe) por el mensaje que pone (*"No has introducido todos los datos necesarios"*) hace referencia al `if (isset(`  y no al `if ($sth == false)`. El orden de las llaves no es el correcto, pon un sangrado correcto y lo verás más claro.

Comment: con los datos que has puesto anteriormente (el array del var_export) la sql puede ser erronea, puesto que los dias martes, viernes los tienes a null (no estan definidos en tu $_POST). Añade un `echo $sql;` y muestranos la sql que te forma

Comment: @Jakala INSERT INTO tablaempresa, per_contacto, tel_contacto, email, hor_disp_inicio, hor_disp_final, lunes, martes, miercoles, jueves, viernes, numero_serie, modelo_maquina, ip_maquina, comentario) values ('prueba', 'cO -- None --', '942197322', 'hhhivpc1.w1m@20minut', '09:00', '15:00', 'Disponible', '', 'Disponible', 'Disponible', '', '1231312312', 'MP3004', '192.168.20.14', 'ghgfh')

Comment: si es esa la sql, te falta un parentesis despues del INTO

Comment: @Jakala Perdona ha sido un error al escribirlo, el parentesis existe. ( los datos se introducen en la base de datos correctamente )

Comment: El problema que estás teniendo es en parte debido a una mezcla impropia de cosas, por ejemplo, querer emitir código Javascript cuando estás trabajando con código en el servidor. Esto es posible, pero hoy día es curioso que existiendo Ajax muchos programadores sigan con prácticas como esta. Sí usas Ajax y en el servidor escribes un código controlado que devuelva al cliente el dato que sea, ya lo tendrías resuelto, tendrías un código claro, entendible y práctico. Quizá no sería siquiera necesario hacer redirecciones y cosas parecidas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El fallo lo tienes en la lógica de esta fragmento de código:

```
if ($sth == false) {
    print_r($query->errorInfo());
    die ('Erreur execute');

   header("location: exito.php");
   exit;


} else { 

     $message = "No has introducido todos los datos necesarios";
     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
     header('Refresh: 0; URL=../index.html');

 }
```

Lo que estas diciendo en este código, es que en caso de que la query vaya mal que pinte la traza de error y "muera". Y que en caso de que vaya bien que te pinte el alert (por lo que siempre que se graba en la base de datos se muestra el alert). Además nunca llegas al header ("location"). El código tendría más sentido así:

```
if ($sth == false) {
     print_r($query->errorInfo());
     $message = "No has introducido todos los datos necesarios";
     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
     header('Refresh: 0; URL=../index.html');

} else { 

     header("location: exito.php");
     exit;
 }
```

Comment: Correcto, asi es. Ahi estaba mi problema. Muchas gracias!